# Need for loop jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code

```
$('.button1').click(function(){
    $('.docs_main2,.docs_main3,.docs_main4,.docs_main5,.docs_main6,.docs_main7,.docs_main8,.docs_main9,.docs_main10,.docs_main11,.docs_main12,.docs_main13,.docs_main14,.docs_main15,.docs_main16,.docs_main17,.docs_main18,.docs_main19').fadeOut("slow");
});

$('.button2').click(function(){
    $('.docs_main1,.docs_main3,.docs_main4,.docs_main5,.docs_main6,.docs_main7,.docs_main8,.docs_main9,.docs_main10,.docs_main11,.docs_main12,.docs_main13,.docs_main14,.docs_main15,.docs_main16,.docs_main17,.docs_main18,.docs_main19').fadeOut("slow");
});
```

In this, when I click on "button1" class name, then other button 2 to 18 would be hidden.
When I click on "button2" class name, then other button 3 to 18 and button1 would be hidden.

I need this code in for loops. Can some one provide me this.

Comment: Can you post the HTML? There are likely better ways to do this than using loops.

Comment: @RobH Why do you care ? It's a basic but legitimate question. By *"in for loops"* it should probably be understood that OP simply doesn't want the repetition he now has.

Comment: @dystroy I was trying to ascertain whether the 'for loops' were a requirement or not. I didn't mean to cause offense.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a for loop, but when you have code that does selections on `"name"+index`that would indicate a deeper problem in the semantics and structure of your code.

I suggest adding a class (with a semantic meaningful name) and add that to all elements (simply `doc_main` might work` so for example:

```
<div class="doc_main1">
```

Becomes

```
<div class="doc_main">
```

Which would allow you to do

```
$(".doc_main").hide();
```

Elements can have multiple classes. So if you need to keep the unique class in addition (need more information to tell) you can do that too.

If you *must* use a for loop (and I've *never* seen a similar case which *had* to use a for loop). You can do:

```
$('.button1').click(function(){
    for(var i=2;i<=19;i++){ 
       $(".doc_main"+i).fadeOut("slow"); // please don't do this :(
    }
});
```

If I may add one last tip - choose meaningful names for your classes and variables.

Answer (score 0):

Can you edit the HTML? Why not assign common classes to the elements for each button (e.g. "hide1" and "hide2"), like this:

```
<elem class="docs_main2 hide1"/>
<elem class="docs_main3 hide1 hide2"/>
....
<elem class="docs_main18 hide1 hide2"/>
```

This way you can just select by the common class:

```
$('.button1').click(function(){
   $('.hide1').fadeOut("slow");
});

$('.button2').click(function(){
   $('.hide2').fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't this get a bit complicated if there were also `.button3`, `.button4`, etc?

Comment: Potentially, yes. That's one of the issues with the question. If we have no idea what he's trying to do, it's hard to suggest the correct solution. As @Robh astutely pointed out in his comment to the OP, this sounds like a homework question, given the request for "code in for loops".

Answer (score 0):

Shorter and better version of your code

```
$('.button1,.button2').click(function () {
    $('[class^=docs_main]').not('.docs_main' + $(this).attr('class')replace('button', '')).fadeOut("slow");
});
```

References

[.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

[attribute-equals-selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

[**^** attribute-starts-with-selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

[.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

[.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: Might want to use the attribute contains selector rather than the attribute starts with selector, in case the elements in question have more than one class.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.button1').click(function(){
  for(var i = 2; i <= 18; i++ ){
   $('.docs_main'+i).fadeOut("slow");
  }
});
$('.button2').click(function(){
  for(var i = 3; i <= 18; i++ ){
   $('.docs_main'+i).fadeOut("slow");
  }
  $('.docs_main1').fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Although I would strongly recommend to edit your html because things like this give headaches in future maintenances.

Answer (score 0):

> *"I need this code in for loops."*

No you don't. Doing it with a for loop is a fairly trivial exercise, but what you really need is to better structure your html. You don't show what you have, but I would recommend that you give your `button` elements a common class and use a `data-` attribute to indicate the associated elements:

```
<button class="button" data-associated="dm1">Button 1</button>
<button class="button" data-associated="dm2">Button 2</button>
```

And then give all of those `docs_mainX` elements the same class (drop the number) so that you can easily select them all at once, while giving them unique ids (or unique `data-` attributes of some kind) to match them to the associated buttons:

```
<div id="dm1" class="docs_main">blah blah</div>
<div id="dm2" class="docs_main">blah blah</div>
```

Because then your jQuery becomes something short and simple like this:

```
$(".button").click(function() {
    $(".docs_main").not("#" + $(this).attr("data-associated")).fadeOut("slow");
});
```

(EDIT) P.S. If your button elements happen to be inside the `.docs_mainX` elements and the idea is to hide all but the one that was clicked it becomes even simpler, because you don't need any ids or `data-` attributes, you can just drop the number off the class to make them all `.doc_main` and then do something like this:

```
$(".button").click(function() {
    $(".docs_main").not($(this).closest(".docs_main")).fadeOut("slow");
});
// OR
var $buttons = $(".button").click(function() {
    $buttons.not(this).closest(".docs_main").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Comment: Data attributes for application logic are a bad idea in99 percent of cases. Why not save the data in JavaScript? Why should the Dom be the source of truth here? Edit - not the downvoter

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - Even if you save the data in the JS the button elements still need some kind of unique identifier in the html as a key to lookup in the JS - otherwise how do you know which button was clicked? But once you have the unique identification in the html you don't need any further data in the JS.

Comment: No, they actually really really don't. There is no reason for the HTML to be the source of truth. You can easily create associations without it http://jsfiddle.net/JMmJ6/

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - Well yes, and I've done [a simplified version of that](http://jsfiddle.net/JMmJ6/1/) in the past, but even that relies on the HTML structure having matched pairs of elements in the right order so the HTML is still the source of truth. What if they were out of order, or if each button had more than one associated element?

Comment: Optimally - you'd model the elements in a much more meaningful way - where you have backing JS objects that each contain the relevant data. Those objects would have access to _both_ the button and the other list item (that's why listItems is an array with references to the original order in my code and not implicit).